# What is the quickest way to replace a variable if a condition is met?

Tags: javascript

I often use code of this form:

```
object.attribute=object.attribute=="forbidden value"?
                 object.attribute:"allowed value";
```

But it has 3 redundancies of object.attribute, which makes refractoring harder.
Is there a way to reduce this amount of redundancies?

Comment: Since it already exists you can drop one: `if (object.attribute=="forbidden value")                object.attribute="allowed value";` which is what I would GUESS your code was supposed to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given operator sets the object attribute to "allowed value" only if it doesn't already have the value "forbidden value". If this is what was intended (was it?) then an equivalent is:

```
if (object.attribute != "forbidden value") {object.attribute = "allowed value";}
```

i.e. a forbidden value remains.

But this seems a bit odd - still without more context we can't know if it's what was intended.